# Invalid mapping on handler class public java.lang.String com.emusicstore.controller.admin.AdminHome.adminPage()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

When I try to introduce Spring Security into my code, I get this error. Spring version is 4.3.18, spring security version is 3.2.7.

The error is as follows:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mapping on handler class [com.emusicstore.controller.admin.AdminHome]: public java.lang.String com.emusicstore.controller.admin.AdminHome.adminPage()
Jan 28, 2020 10:04:53 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mapping on handler class [com.emusicstore.controller.admin.AdminHome]: public java.lang.String com.emusicstore.controller.admin.AdminHome.adminPage()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5068)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5584)enter code here
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1863)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:828)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$1/1110694198.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid mapping on handler class [com.emusicstore.controller.admin.AdminHome]: public java.lang.String com.emusicstore.controller.admin.AdminHome.adminPage()
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$1.inspect(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:239)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector$1.doWith(MethodIntrospector.java:72)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:530)
    at org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector.selectMethods(MethodIntrospector.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1692)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.path()[Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:251)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$1.inspect(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:235)
    ... 67 more

Jan 28, 2020 10:04:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jan 28, 2020 10:04:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/eMusicStore] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 28, 2020 10:04:53 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/eMusicStore] registered the JDBC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Jan 28, 2020 10:04:53 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [/eMusicStore] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityCorrelator$1] (value [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityCorrelator$1@9ba4aa]) and a value of type [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityId] (value [dc8d1aa0-2727-41a2-8fb7-7f44aa2d6a7a-2]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
[2020-01-28 10:04:53,894] Artifact eMusicStore:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\bin\catalina.bat stop
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Rishav\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_eMusicStore"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Jan 28, 2020 10:05:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
INFO: A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
Jan 28, 2020 10:05:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jan 28, 2020 10:05:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jan 28, 2020 10:05:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jan 28, 2020 10:05:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jan 28, 2020 10:05:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jan 28, 2020 10:05:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jan 28, 2020 10:05:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]

The controllers are as follows :
Home Controller
package com.emusicstore.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestParam(value = "error",required = false)String error,@RequestParam(value = "logout",
    required = false)String logout,Model model){
        if(error!=null){
            model.addAttribute("error","Invalid username and password");
        }

        if(logout!=null){
            model.addAttribute("msg","You have logged out successfully");
        }

        return "login";
    }
}

AdminHome
package com.emusicstore.controller.admin;

import com.emusicstore.model.Product;
import com.emusicstore.service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminHome {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping
    public String adminPage(){

        return "admin";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/productInventory")
    public String productInventory(Model model){
        List<Product> products=productService.getProductList();
        model.addAttribute("products",products);

        return "productInventory";
    }

//    @RequestMapping("/customer")
//    public String customerManagement(Model model){
//        return "customerManagement";
//    }
}

admin.jsp
<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp"%>


<div class="container-wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Administrator page</h1>

            <p class="lead">This is the administrator page!</p>
        </div>

        <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
        <h2>
            Welcome: ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | <a href="<c:url
                value="/j_spring_security_logout" />">Logout</a>
        </h2>
        </c:if>

        <h3>
            <a href="<c:url value="/admin/productInventory" />" >Product Inventory</a>
        </h3>

        <p>Here you can view, check and modify the product inventory!</p>


<%@include file="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" %>
```

I don't seem to understand what the issue is. Before adding Spring Security, it seems to work fine but that could be unrelated. Please help me figure out how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the versions you are using, your Spring-Core version comes from June 2018.
[Spring-Core Versions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core)

And your Spring-Security version comes from Jan 2014. 
[Spring-Security Versions](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core)

Your version of Spring security expect some methods to exist in Spring-Core but they no longer exist in the 2018 version of Spring.

I suggest you upgrade your version of Spring-Security to a version near 4.2.6.RELEASE to fix your problem.